# Trying to download PDF files opens them instead of asking me where to save them

Tags: macos, google-chrome, adobe-acrobat

Recently, every time I try to download a PDF file - such as an attachment in gmail - it is automatically downloaded to my downloads folder and opens in my PDF viewer (Adobe Acrobat), instead of showing me the save file dialog as expected.

I assume it is an integration feature somewhere but no idea if it's a setting in Chrome, or Acrobat. Where can I disable this?

Answer (score -1):

Probably it`s settings regarding default behavior of particular file type.
That is not in Chrome or Acrobat, try to explore settings of PC.
Not shore where is that in MacOS. Maybe in "extensions".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).